# Importing images for manifold Isomap

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

There are 192 x 144 pixel images. They should be imported to a Python list so that the items in the list are NDArray instances. New dataframe should be created from the list and that dataframe should be given to Isomap. `iso.fit(df)` fails with the errors

```
array = array.astype(np.float64)

ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

I have spent more than one day trying to figure out how the NDArrays should be processed and the dataframe loaded with them. No luck. Any help would be appreciated.

```
import pandas as pd
from scipy import misc
import glob
from sklearn import manifold

samples = []

for filename in glob.glob('Datasets/ALOI/32/*.png'): 
    img = misc.imread(filename, mode='I')
    samples.append(img)

df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(samples, coerce_float=True)

iso = manifold.Isomap(n_neighbors=6, n_components=3)
iso.fit(df)
```

Answer (score 1):

If those are gray scale images from the ALOI, you probably want to treat each pixel's brightness as a feature.  Therefore, you should flatten the img array with img.reshape(-1).  The revised code follows:

```
import pandas as pd
from scipy import misc
import glob
from sklearn import manifold

samples = []

for filename in glob.glob('Datasets/ALOI/32/*.png'): 
    img = misc.imread(filename, mode='I')
    # the following line changed
    samples.append(img.reshape(-1))

df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(samples, coerce_float=True)

iso = manifold.Isomap(n_neighbors=6, n_components=3)
iso.fit(df)
```

Comment: Thank you hawley. reshape() it is.